# Centering a search box with CSS

Tags: html, css, search, css-position

This is the main code that positions the box. I need to make the search input along with the other parts always center on any size screen. The input area of the box keeps moving to the far right of the screen, which is a problem.

```
.wsite-search {
    position: relative;
    margin-top:78px;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    margin-left:auto;
}

.wsite-search-input:focus {
    background: #f8f8f8;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.wsite-search-input {
    width: 158px;
    height: 19px;
    border: 0;
    padding: 10px 45px 10px 7px !important;
    font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
    color: #8e8e8e;
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 24px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-weight:300;
}

.wsite-search-button {
    position: absolute;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    border: 0;
    right: 14px;
    top: 10px;
    background: url(submit-button-v3.png) no-repeat 0px 0px;
}
```

Comment: Would you mind creating a JSfiddle? I'm sure I could center it for you but a JSfiddle with relevant HTML and your CSS in it would help me test it better. Thanks.

Comment: Provide HTML code along with css

Comment: Isn't there just a simple way to make the box always centered? I would think it would be straightforward but I keep finding the issue is that the box moves around relative to screen size.

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to center just the input box itself, if so you can center it by using margin

```
margin: 0 50%;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rlynjb/eyjzhj8s/

if you want to center both input and button in the middle. you can wrap those 2 elements in a div tag and use the margin: 0 50% to center both elements.